# Can't deserialise JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have created a Javascript-based application that uses the following JQuery function to de-serialize a JSON object from a specific URL and extrapolate some data out of it. I have taken in consideration 2 JSON objects from two different URLs. These 2 objects contain the exact same data.

When I analyse the first URL via the RESTClient plugin I get the following header:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,80:quic
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 53
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 08:25:52 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

The second URL via the RESTClient plugin gives me the following header instead:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 08:29:20 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The problem is that the JSON object from the first URL is perfectly deserialised, while the second is not.
This is my JQuery function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8085/Metrics/kfc/brands/Metrics/type3/', //one of the two URLs
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return false;
        }
        dataFromServer = data;

        $.each(dataFromServer, function (date, value) {
            dates.push(date);
            values.push(value);
        });

        result.dates = dates;
        result.values = values;
    },

    error: function (msg, url, line) {
        alert('error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)');
        alert('msg = ' + msg + ', url = ' + url + ', line = ' + line);

    }


});

return result.dates;

}
```

Further feedback: the error message displayed in the alert is:

```
error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)
msg = [object Object], url = error, line =
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone could spot where the error my be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the error object look like?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems that object is not created at all

Comment: Your snippet includes the line `return result.dates;`, but your AJAX call operates asynchronously. When your function returns it's unlikely that it will have yet read the data. The parameters you are expecting in your error function are wrong - see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you fix that the error message might give you something useful.

Comment: Is the page making the AJAX request also on `http://localhost:8085`?

Comment: @Mike W: When I change the async to false I get the following error: msg = [object Object], url = error, line = [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8081/MobileMonitor/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8214"  data: no]

Comment: I'm referring to `msg = [object Object]`. Use `console.log(msg)`, not alert

Comment: you sure the response and the response content-type are all same from both the urls? It seems you are not getting a correct response from the second url hence it is triggering the error function, use firebug to see the response headers

Comment: +1 to @Johan... never never use `alert()` to debug ajax or other async JS code. Always use the `console` instead.

Comment: @rps: if you look at the code, when yoo debug, after the async: true line the debugger will jump straight to the error: function (msg, url, line) line. The only thing you can get is the msg, url and line which is displayed by the alert, as I have already shown

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable cross site scripting if your page is not hosted at the same location where both of these services are hosted.

Answer (score -1):

If U have Json string then u want it as a object then follow the code

var object = JSON.parse(your json string);

Comment: The problem is that the JSON string is not obtained, so you can't pass it as a parameter

Comment: jQuery already parses the response as JSON if you specify `dataType: 'json'`, so you don't need to explicitly parse it yourself (and it wouldn't work even if you did call that - `data` is already an object or array, not a string).